# How can I tell which method in my protocol is not implemented?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an iPhone app in Cocoa.

I have a warning in XCode reading "method in protocol not implemented." My protocol has 50 methods.

Is there a way for XCode to efficiently tell me which method(s) is/are not implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Command+4` open the Issue navigator, sort `By Type`, click the arrow before `Incomplete implementation` and you will find the missing method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue navigator angle (+1 @fannheyward), the selector's identified by name in the build transcript.